# URL loader for fonts in angular 17

Tags: css, angular, webpack, sass

I am trying to get webpack to convert font files to data uris in angular 17 and I simply cannot get it to work. I am using the custom webpack builder. I've tried a lot of different takes on the same config, but something like

```
  config.module.rules.push({
    test: /\.(woff(2)?|eot|ttf|otf)$/,
    use: [
      {
        loader: "url-loader",
        options: {
          limit: Infinity,
        },
      },
    ],
  });

  return config;
};
```

As a test, I used a function for `test` in the webpack and printed all the paths, and as far as I can see none of them are font files.

The original issue was with `@import "primeicons/primeicons.css";`, but I've even added

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'MyTest';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 100;
  src: url('Roboto-Medium.ttf') format('ttf');
}
```

to style.scss and still, no font files are presented and nothing is converted to a data url.

Anyone have any experience with custom webpack builders using url-loader in angular 17.